# Populate Drop down based on Selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two drop downs In first I am given names of employees and in second designation. I want that lets say we select First Employee who is PM and TL both then the second drop down should show only PM TM and when we select PM from second in first it shows only those employees which are PM. I also want if it is possible to multi select from first drop down

```
 <select>
<!--This is main selectbox.-->
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>Brendon</option>
<option>Davin</option>
<option>Bobby</option>
</select>
<select class="sub">
<!--another selectbox for option one.-->
<option>TL</option>
<option>PM</option>
</select>
<select class="sub">
<!--another selectbox for option two.-->
<option>PM</option>
<option>TL</option>
</select>
<select class="sub">
<!--another selectbox for option three.-->
<option>Developer</option>

 </select>
<select class="sub">
<!--another selectbox for option four.-->
<option>Developer</option>

 </select>
```

Here is the Fiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/7CmYj/39/

Comment: I suggest you to use css classes for the options of the first select to specify selectable options on the second select. Then will be so easy, with jquery, to hide not matching options when you select any from one or other select.

Comment: To be able to select multiple options in select, the only way is to add the 'multiple' attribute to it. But then it will be displayed as selection list, not as drop-down.

If multiple selection wo'nt be usual use case, you may want to add/remove this attribute from javascript when something (like ctrl+click over the select) happens.

Comment: @bitifet can you help out please how to do with css or please explain mor

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like in this example

```
a more structured way to do these actions
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CmYj/92

Comment: This just appending the list. If any body is developer it just show developer list appends what selected first

Comment: actually i copy pasted the old url. My bad, here the link https://jsfiddle.net/7CmYj/93/

Answer (score 0):

Dirty and untested. But. despite probable typos, should work:

```
<select id="employee">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option class="tl">John</option>
    <option class="pm">Brendon</option>
    <option class="tl pm">Davin</option>
    <option class="pm dev">Bobby</option>
</select>

<select id="designation">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="tl">TL</option>
    <option value="pm">PM</option>
    <option value="dev">Developer</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function automate(){
            var empl = $("select#employee");
            var emplOpts = $("option", empl);
            var des = $("select#designation");
            var desOpts = $("option", des);

            empl.on("change", function(){
                var me = $(this);
                desOpts.each(function(){
                    var currOpt = $(this);
                    if(me.hasClass(currOpt.attr("value"))) {
                        currOpt.show();
                    } else {
                        currOpt.hide();
                    };  
                });
            });

            des.on("change", function(){
                var v = des.val();
                if (! v.length) {
                    emplOpts.show();
                } else {
                    emplOpts.each(function(){
                        var me=$(this);
                        if (me.hasClass(v)) {
                            me.show();
                        } else {
                            me.hide();
                        };  
                    }); 
                };  
            }); 

    });     
</script>
```